# SQLite - игнорирование дубликатов в таблице

Tags: android, sqlite

Знаю что есть игнорирования дубликатов в таблице. При создании таблицы это как-то указывается, но не могу найти как. Вот запрос по созданию таблицы

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + NewsTable.ID + " integer primary key, "
                + NewsTable.AUTHOR + " text, " + NewsTable.TITLE + " text, " + NewsTable.DESCRIPTION + " text, "
                + NewsTable.URL + " text, " + NewsTable.URL_TO_IMG + " text, " + NewsTable.DATE + " integer)");
```

Если я правильно понимаю нужно какое-то поле, по которому будет сверка. Пусть это будет NewsTable.TITLE. Кто подскажет как это указать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За уникальные значения отвечает **UNIQUE**

Ограничения UNIQUE можно использовать, чтобы убедиться, что в отдельные столбцы, не включенные в первичный ключ, не вводятся повторяющиеся значения. Хотя уникальность значений ограничения UNIQUE и PRIMARY KEY гарантируют в равной степени, в случае, когда необходимо обеспечить уникальность в столбце или комбинации столбцов, которые не являются первичными ключевыми, вместо ограничения PRIMARY KEY следует использовать ограничение UNIQUE.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NewsTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
title VARCHAR (48) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
AUTHOR TEXT,
DESCRIPTION TEXT,
URL TEXT,
URL_TO_IMG TEXT,
DATE INTEGER );
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что надо!

Answer (score 2):

[UNIQUE](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/unique.php):

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+
" ("+NewsTable.ID+" integer primary key, "+
     NewsTable.AUTHOR+" text, "+
     NewsTable.TITLE+" text UNIQUE, "+
     NewsTable.DESCRIPTION+" text, "+
     NewsTable.URL+" text, "+NewsTable.URL_TO_IMG+" text, "+
     NewsTable.DATE+" integer)");
```